# Use named range variable name dynamically in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, named-ranges

I am new to Google sheets.
I have one sheet with multiple named ranges. Each range is named with "company_{{ id }}" e.g. "company_snapchat".

I have list of company ids as follows:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Company ID     |  Sum of Costs    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      snapchat       |    <formula>     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      facebook       |    <formula>     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

In the formula I want to reference its named range as `"company_"&a2`. However it doesn't work.

Comment: does this `=INDIRECT("company_"&A2)` paste to the `<formula>` cell answer your question? or automatically create named range when new data added, might need to use apps-script (macro)

Comment: Hello AndroidDev, does @zummontt's suggestion work for your situation? If not, would you mind providing more details about your issue? Cheers!

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. Would you please add an answer to be approved?

Comment: I appreciate it and be happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INDIRECT()` to refer value in a cell as cell reference

`=INDIRECT("company_"&A2)`

Normally we work with `A1` or `R1C1` but also work with named range too